# Which device can be used to extend the range of wireless router?

Tags: wifi

My apartment and my brother's one are approximately 40 meters away, and we want to share the same network. I wonder is there a device to extend the range of a router? I'm currently using Cisco Linksys E3000 with Time Warner Cable service, and he was not be able to detect my network. Or is there a wireless router that has a wider range?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's called "Wireless Range Extender", a quick google should lead you to some explanation.

Not to sound rude, but *have you actually done any research about it on the internet*, even pasting you question verbatim to Google yields useable results.

Comment: Yeah, I did some searches but some talk about wireless extender, others talks about variety of similar products, so I wasn't sure what's the right name for it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

See if your router supports [WDS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_Distribution_System).  If not consider getting a couple routers that support WDS, and join them together.

You may want to look at alternate firmware for your routers.  Some will not support WDS with the stock firmware, but if you flash it with dd-wrt, or something else, and then use WDS.